# vim and latex-box

Tags: vim, plugins

I installed the vim plugin latex-box but I am having trouble getting it to compile my Latex file. The docs say it uses latexmk to do the compiling, and I have that installed and it works when called by itself.
But when I use the plugin's `\ll` command to compile I get an error that says 'cannot run latexmk in background without a VIM server'. I cannot find an explanation of why this error would occur in the plugin documentation.

**EDIT:**

I found a solution to this issue, but ran into others.

To fix this, you need to install the full version of vim (which is different depending on your OS) which will include things like server support. I suggest doing this even if you don't use this plugin because it will fix not been able to copy/paste from/to vim. In (K)ubuntu, install the package `vim-gtk`.

Start vim like this `vim --servername SOMETHING file.tex`

After doing this, the servername error went away and the compilation went through but the output from latexmk shows up on top of the file I'm editing. It doesn't overwrite it, it's just displayed on top of the text. When I move the cursor and vim highlights a word or bracket, that appears back on the screen. The only quick way I found to get rid of the compiler output is to scroll the file up and back down, that makes the text appear again.

Comment: Is there any fix for Mac OS? I'm running vim from Mac terminal and it does not understand the option --servername :(

Comment: I actually stopped using latex-box and linked F9 to a latexmk command to run the code through latex. I use a PDF viewer that reloads the file if it changes, so after latexmk finishes I see the changes right away.

Comment: I see. Not a bad solution. Any reason why you stop using latex-box?

Comment: I stopped because I could obtain the functionality from latex-box through other plugins that don't have the redraw issue (ultisnips, surround, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can ask vim to redraw the screen like this:

```
:redraw!
```

Append that command after running your latex command.